# How to create a CSS grid with 3 columns having column flow?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want a grid layout with unlimited number of elements in 3 columns, and as many rows are needed, like so:

```
[1] [5] [9]
[2] [6] [10]
[3] [7] [11]
[4] [8]
```

I can accomplish it using JavaScript, but I would like to know the way to do it only with CSS.

My CSS is:

```
.parent-div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

However with above CSS, I get:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11]
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Not possible with CSS based on your current premise of Css-grid . Column-count is what you require here.

Comment: Yes indeed, column-count was required. Thank you.